# Why do I have brace-initialise (value-initialise) this object for it to be constexpr?

Tags: c++, constexpr

I think I have a case where if I don't brace/value-initialise an object it can't be constexpr, but I think it's only happening on some compilers, this compiles on 'my' version of Visual Studio:

```
template <typename T>
struct MyClass
{
    constexpr MyClass() = default;
    

    int member;
};

template <typename T>
constexpr MyClass<T> makeMyClass(T t)
{
    MyClass<T> temp;
           // {}^^^
    // If I keep the constructor and brace-initialise here the error goes away.
    temp.member = 3;
    // Uninitialized variable 'temp' in 'constexpr' function, why do I have to initialise?
    return temp;
}


int main()
{
    constexpr auto myclassobj = makeMyClass(6);
    //^^^ If I add constexpr before this line AND I don't 
    //brace-initialise temp then I get the error: 
    //error: uninitialized variable ‘temp’ in ‘constexpr’ function
}
```

Am I doing something wrong with constexpr constructor defaulted? If I don't { } brace initialise then it isn't that constructor that's being called anymore? Is that what the error is? That if I don't brace-initialise then it's calling a constructor that's not constexpr?

Comment: Instead of commenting, could you post one complete version of your code that works, and one complete version that doesn't?

Comment: @NathanOliver Basically for this to compile I have to brace initialise { } temp if I want it to be constexpr. The warnings tell me that I have to 'initialise' temp, it's not enough to just create and not { } value initialise.

Comment: Your default constructor is not initializing `member`.  Constexpr requires that all members be initialized.

Comment: @JDługosz "Constexpr requires that all members be initialized", oh, that's it then. Do you mean if the constructor is constexpr or if the object is used outside in a constexpr expression?

Comment: @Zebrafish it doesn't complain that the constructor marked `constexpr` _isn't_.  It only complains if you try to use it to make a `constexpr` value.

Comment: @JDługosz Yes, I removed the constexpr from the constructor, the error still happens, it's because of the constexpr in main... very interesting. So much learning to do.

Comment: This is allowed in C++20, since the restriction that variables have to be initialized at declaration was removed.

Comment: @Artyer If they don't have to be initialised how does the compiler know what they if they need to be compile-time known? Or is it just that it complains when the certain members it needs aren't initialised?

Answer (score 1):

Your defaulted constructor does not cause `member` to be initialized.

A `constexpr` object must have all its fields initialized<sup>※</sup>.  I've seen the same thing happen for arrays where not every cell was initialized.

```
template <typename T>
struct MyClass
{
    constexpr MyClass() = default;
    
    int member {};  // add this initialize and it will be picked up by the default constructor
};
```

### Footnote

**※** This is the rule for C++17.  It was removed in C++20.

Answer (score 1):

The basic problem is that your default constructor cannot be constexpr because the class contains a `int` that would [remain unitialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization) with the default constructor.

If you use the [aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization), an empty braces implies that you value-initialize the members of the class, hence the object is completely initialized and you can use it in a `constexpr` expression.